# How to match time zones using arshaw full calendar?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, fullcalendar

I am working on a project using arshaw full calendar. The system I am developing is Coach - student portal where student can book coach around the world. The issue I am having is : how I can maintain Timezones as student can be from different timezone and coach from different timezone due to different countries. Currently the issue is when student book a coach for any date at 10:00 AM morning from INDIA which is in GMT+ 5:30 and the coach is from Germany which is UTC+01:00. So, due to timezones both student and coach cannot meet on particular time. How I can solve this? How to solve timezones for different timezone while creating an event on Arshaw full calendar?

I appreciate if someone can help me. I am using arshaw full calendar version 2.0.3

Looking forward to hear from you.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save all of your times in UTC and render all of your time locally (which should happen by default).

Comment: Just have all your times in the ISO 8601 format "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" and you don't have to think about it

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Also, timezone `'local'` is not default. You have to specify that

Comment: @RichardHermanson Yes, local isn't default -- thanks for clarifying. He should still convert between UTC and local times or else he could have problems, especially if users are booking dates -- depending on how he does the booking, most likely the date/time the user selects will be a local time (meaning he needs to convert it before saving). That's really the only extra step needed, besides setting 'local' as the timezone on the calendar.